# Navigation swipe gesture issue

Tags: ios

I am facing a issue in `UINavigationController` swipe back and forth.
I have two classes, one is main class which has a navigation bar and a second class. When I navigate from main class to second class and swipe left to right and then again right to left without removing the finger and then came to any class then it shows the navigation bar of main class rather than the navigation bar of current class.Please help and suggest the idea. I am very thankful to you.

Thanks
Ravinder

Comment: Mention some of your code that you have written to manage the navigation bar in both class and mention what language you use to develop the App. is it swift or Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Janmenjaya,

Yes, the language is Objective C.

Actually, the navigation bar is created using storyboard not programmatically and to manage swipe between two class, In main class, I have used  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO] and then used  self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil; inside viewWillAppear function, and then used [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]; inside prepareForSegue function.

And in second class, i have used [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; inside viewWillAppear function.

And in third class, i have used [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; and then
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
inside viewWillAppear function.

Thanks 
Ravinder